# Checking the Appearance of Website on different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am learning Web Designing .i have to check the appearance of website at different time in different browsers.there are some paid software tools exist like http://crossbrowsertesting.com/ and browserstack.com but they are paid .How to check compatibility with different browsers (mainly old browsers.).what is the most convenient way for this   and any free software in which we can check ??

Comment: Well it depends on the number of browsers you're supposed to support. This kind of service is usefull when you need to support/test very exotic browsers, but for most of them you may just want to install different browsers and test with each periodically. Testing with old FF or Chrome is almost useless as they're permanently versionned, testing old IE version can be done through virtual machines.

Comment: lmgify http://inspirationfeed.com/resources/tools/free-cross-browser-testing-tools/

Comment: if its just about view and not features....search google with `check website view in different browsers`, it shows lot of URLS to check the design compatibility! :)

Answer (score 2):

this is not 100% answer to your question but check out this website: http://caniuse.com/ - there you can see, which html5+css3 elements you can use. Might be helpful when developing or planning or whatever :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you'll need to check on all main browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Explorer), plus old and current versions of each I recommend using [**Old Apps**](http://www.oldapps.com/category/browsers) which allows you to download old, outdated versions of all main browsers.  Since many people don't update their browsers when they should, this is the best way to simulate viewing your web pages as they would.

For a more complicated way of viewing true Internet Explorer 6 & 7, I would suggest installing a virtual machine on your PC.  If you're on a Mac, set up Bootcamp, boot into Windows, then install a virtual machine in that.  Obviously it's best to have a true Mac and true PC, but this will do in a pinch.

First and foremost, check out [**Old Apps**](http://www.oldapps.com/category/browsers).  It should be *the browsers you're looking for*.